# F# Charting LiveChart implementation Observable

Tags: types, charts, f#, signature, observable

I'm trying to implement a live chart from FSharp Charting. The documentation [here](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Charting/reference/fsharp-charting-livechart.html) gives a type signature for a Live Line Chart as:

```
static member LiveChart.Line : data:IObservable<#seq<'a1 * 'a2>> * ?Name:string * ?Title:string * ?Color:Color * ?XTitle:string * ?YTitle:string -> GenericChart (requires 'a1 :> key and 'a2 :> value)
```

I have an IObservable that emits a time series of data with times and values, but what in the world is IObservable<#seq<'a1 * 'a2>>?! And why is the argument to this function a gigantic tuple?

Comment: Example look? http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Charting/LiveChartSamples.html

Comment: That's hardly an example. It talks about Observables, but doesn't show how they are implemented. I currently have an Observable that emits a DateTime * float. How do I plug it into LiveChart.Line?

Answer (score 3):

Earlier with Observable and Live Chart don't worked, but i wrote simple example:

```
open System
open System.Windows.Forms
open System.Reactive.Linq
open FSharp.Charting

[<EntryPoint>]
[<STAThread>]
let main argv = 

    Application.EnableVisualStyles()
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault false

    let form = new Form(Visible = true, TopMost = true, 
                            Width = 700, Height = 500)
    let rand = new Random()
    let obs = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)).
                 ObserveOn(WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Current)
                |> Observable.map(fun _ -> DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(),rand.Next(0,21))

    let one  = LiveChart.FastLineIncremental(obs,Name="Simple Example")

    one.ShowChart()
    Application.Run form
    0
```

Perhaps this code will help to solve your problem. After some minutes work:

[image]

If i, as a novice, made serious mistakes, I hope the more experienced members of the site will correct me. I apologize in advance if I gave bad advice

Answer (score 2):

You need an Observable that emits a sequence of `DateTime * float` values rather than a single data point (can't make much of a line chart out of a single point, I suppose).

If you only have an Observable that emits a single data point at a time, I suppose what you want to do is to have another Observable that will accumulate a series of observations in a single sequence, and use that as the data source for your chart.

The argument to that function is a "tuple", because that enables using optional arguments (and skipping them otherwise). It's a common pattern to use static members in order to benefit from things like optional arguments or overloading, which are not supported by regular let-bound F# functions.